# Adding a virtual NIC in centos 7 not working on the cloud

Tags: centos, cloud

How can I add a virtual NIC with a specific MAC address on a cloud server?

I recently acquired a cloud based service with `Centos 7` in it.

I have an application that runs on a specific MAC address only.

How can I clone this MAC address or add another virtual NIC with this MAC address?

I tried adding a virtual NIC like eth0:1 , it got added fine, but the MAC address is the same as eth0, however I need a different MAC address.

Comment: Interface aliases do not have their own MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to route any traffic over it, you could use the `dummy` interface

eg before:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0c:d8:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now we use the `dummy` module, and get a new interface:

```
$ sudo modprobe dummy
$ sudo ip link set dummy0 address 10:20:30:40:50:60
$ ip link show dummy0                            
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether 10:20:30:40:50:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This has created an interface called `dummy0` with the MAC address we requested.

Another option could be to create a `tap` device:

```
$ sudo ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
$ sudo ip link set tap0 address 10:20:30:40:50:61
$ ip link show tap0
4: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
    link/ether 10:20:30:40:50:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

With `tap` devices you can call it any name you like, even *cheat* and call it `eth1`.

Comment: Thx Mr, @Stephen Harris

Lately I contacted the Hosting service provider support and they told me that they have some restriction and the mac cannot be cloned or changed on any interface, Strange!
Any way later I moved to Digital Ocean hosting provider and selected Ubuntu 12.4 as OS, and I was successfully able to create a dummy interface by using

`ip link add link eth0 address 11:22:33:44:55:66 eth0.1 type macvlan
ifconfig eth0.1 up
ifconfig eth0.1 10.0.0.2`

Thanks for your advise, I will try it again when get a chance.